# Сейф — несгораемым шкаф

Tags: значение-слов, семантика, синонимы

Почему *сейф* также называют *несгораемым шкафом*?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что думают, что это одно и то же. На самом деле не каждый сейф является огнеупорным и не каждый несгораемый шкаф защищён от взлома.

Answer (score 2):

Это ошибка. Не всякий сейф огнестоек. Сейф (от англ. safe, буквально — безопасный, надёжный) может быть предназначен для защиты от взлома, или от огня, или от взлома и от огня одновременно.